# How to find the first highest number when there are more than one in a Javascript Object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects that I want to find the highest value of the key 'saving'.  I've used this:

```
maxSaving = tableResults.reduce((prev, current)=> ( (prev.saving > current.saving) ? prev : current),0)
```

Which correctly gives me the highest result in the array.  The issue I have is that it's always the last instance of the highest result if there are multiple results for the highest number and I want the first, not the last.

I thought something like this would work but it doesn't:

```
maxSaving = tableResults.reduce((prev, current)=> ( (prev.saving > current.saving && prev.saving != current.saving) ? prev : current),0)
```

I really can't figure it out and I am new to using reduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to make a change **ONLY** when `current.saving` **is greater than** `prev.saving` - this should prevent replacing the first match with the second and so on. So something like this should do it:

```
maxSaving = tableResults.reduce((prev, current)=> current.saving > prev.saving ? current : prev)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your array kinda looks like this.

- Use reduce to find the highest number in the saving key
- start with the first object as the initial maximum.

In this code if you have 2 elements with the same highest value, the code will return only the first occurrence because `maxObject` value is only updated if the current value is higher

```js
//this is just a sample array
const results = [
  { saving: 100, index: 0 },
  { saving: 200, index: 1 },
  { saving: 500, index: 2 },
  { saving: 150, index: 3 },
  { saving: 300, index: 4 },
  { saving: 500, index: 5 },
];

const maxSavingObject = results.reduce((maxObject, currentObject) => {
  return currentObject.saving > maxObject.saving ? currentObject : maxObject;
}, results[0]); 


console.log('Object with the highest saving:', maxSavingObject);
```

Comment: You could explain what the essential difference is with their (first) code: your answer focuses on using `reduce`, but they were already doing that. There is another factor that makes the difference though.

Comment: yes, that is because the `maxObject` only updates if the saving value of the `currentObject` is higher than the `maxObject` so if you find 2 or more elements with `saving: 500` (for this example) `maxSavingObject` will return the first ocurrence only

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those scenarios where you should *not* provide the initial value as second argument to `reduce`. Moreover, the value 0 is just wrong for such initial value, since the accumulator is assumed to be an object, not an integer.

Apart from that you should just change `>` to `>=` and you're done.

```
tableResults.reduce((prev, current) => prev.saving >= current.saving ? prev : current)
```